# Selenium connection refused within docker

Tags: laravel, docker, selenium-webdriver, laravel-dusk

I'm attempting to use Laravel Dusk alongside Selenium to run browser tests. I have my platform and selenium running within docker that are composed together in the same dockerfile.

Each time I try to run `php artisan dusk` I get the error messsage:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.63)
```

I have tried switching APP URL (localhost runs on port 8990) in every combination alongside other flags within `DuskTestCase`. Selenium grid opens correctly at `http://127.0.0.1:4444/`

**docker-compose.yml**

```
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.9.1-20230508
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  edge:
    image: selenium/node-edge:4.9.1-20230508
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:4.9.1-20230508
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.9.1-20230508
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
```

**DuskTestCase.php**

```
$options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(collect([
    $this->shouldStartMaximized() ? '--start-maximized' : '--window-size=1920,1080',
])->unless($this->hasHeadlessDisabled(), function (Collection $items) {
    return $items->merge([
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--headless=new',
        '--whitelisted-ips=""',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
    ]);
})->all());

return RemoteWebDriver::create(
    'http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
    ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
)
);
```

I'm running out of things to try at this point. For reference, my system uses Ubuntu.